# Nested blocks and ERB

Tags: ruby, block, erb, yield

For the life of me, I can't figure out why this doesn't work as expected.

**Code:**

```
require 'erb'

def say_hello(name)
  "Nice to see you, #{ name }!"
end

def greetings
  template = <<-TEMPLATE
Hello!
<%= yield %>
Goodbye!
  TEMPLATE
  ERB.new(template).result(binding)
end

people = ['Aaron', 'Bob', 'Tim', 'Juan']
t = greetings do
  people.each do |p|
    say_hello(p)
  end
end

puts t
```

(a bit contrived, I know, but it'll serve the point.)

**What I Expect:**

```
Hello!
Nice to see you, Aaron!
Nice to see you, Bob!
Nice to see you, Tim!
Nice to see you, Juan!
Goodbye!
```

**What I Get:**

```
Hello!
['Aaron', 'Bob', 'Tim', 'Juan']
Goodbye!
```

**Thoughts:**

I'm guessing this is happening because the interior block (beginning with `people.each`) gets coerced into a string before the block executes. Perhaps ERB doesn't like how I'm trying to inject a new block of constructed text into its template.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of `each` is the array itself, not the return value of the block:

```
people.each do |p|
  say_hello(p)
end
# => ['Aaron', 'Bob', 'Tim', 'Juan']
```

You should use `map`, which returns the array of return values from the block:

```
people.map do |p|
  say_hello(p)
end
# => ["Nice to see you, Aaron!", "Nice to see you, Bob!", "Nice to see you, Tim!", "Nice to see you, Juan!"]
```

You will also need to concatenate the array to render it properly:

```
t = greetings do
  people.map do |p|
    say_hello(p)
  end.join("\n")
end
```

Comment: `The return value of each is the array itself, not the return value of the block:` – that was the missing link for me. Thanks so much!